# Extra overhead in MASQUERADE target

Tags: iptables

There's a part in iptables manual concerning SNAT and MASQUERADE targets. I know the key difference between the two, but I don't fully get the following sentence:

> It is still possible to use the MASQUERADE target instead of SNAT even
>   though you do have a static IP, however, it is not favorable since it
>   will add extra overhead, and there may be inconsistencies in the
>   future which will thwart your existing scripts and render them
>   "unusable".

Does anyone know what "extra overhead" is in this case?